# Navigate with arguments - DART 3

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I try to use the official documentation of Flutter to pass arguments.
I need some help.
The documentation : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments
Maybe it's about i use statefull class and the documentation use only stateless?
main.dart :

```
`import 'dart:io';

import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/PassArgumentsScreen.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/ScreenArguments.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Auth.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Password.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Term.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Platform.isAndroid
      ? await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey:"AIzaSyDqCXX9h8O4ieJPPCIeqCzs3UUarhDWWEk",
    appId:"1:150239692586:android:0a00b7f597f48794b5c053",
    messagingSenderId:"150239692586",
    projectId:"chopetonbts-16bc8",
  ),
  )
      : await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Chope Ton BTS',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const AuthScreen(),
        '/TermScreen': (context) => const TermScreen(email: '',),
        '/PasswordScreen': (context) => const PasswordScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}`
```

PassArgumentsScreen.dart :

```
`import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class PassArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/TermScreen';

  final String email;

  const PassArgumentsScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.email,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
`
```

ScreenArguments.dart :

```
`
class ScreenArguments {
  final String _email;

  ScreenArguments(this._email);
}
`
```

Auth.dart :

```
``
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Guest.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Password.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/Term.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/ScreenArguments.dart';
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/screens/PassArgumentsScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'PassArgumentsScreen.dart';
import 'ScreenArguments.dart';

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  //const AuthScreen({super.key});
  //final Function(int) onChangedStep;
  static const routeName = '/';

  Function(int) onChangedStep(int i) {
    // TODO: implement onChangeStep
    throw UnimplementedError();
   }


  const AuthScreen({super.key, onChangedStep});
  //const AuthScreen({required Key? key, required this.onChangeStep,}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<AuthScreen> createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _authKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final RegExp emailRegex = RegExp(r"[a-z0-9\.-]+@[a-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-z]+");
  String email= '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as AuthScreen;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(args.email),
        ),
        body: Center(
          //monte le champ lorsque l'on écrit
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'Bienvenue sur\n'.toUpperCase(),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30.0),
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: 'ChopeTonDiplome'.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Esquive la case "Pôle emploi"',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 50.0,
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _authKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Entre ton email'),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _email = value),
                        validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty || !emailRegex.hasMatch(value) ? "Merci d'entrer une adresse email valide" : null,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Ex: john.walter@domaine.fr',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          elevation: 0,
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 15.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed:  !emailRegex.hasMatch(_email) ? null : () {
                          if(_authKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            print(_email);
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, PassArgumentsScreen.routeName,
                            arguments: ScreenArguments(
                            _email,
                            ),
                            );
                            //widget.onChangedStep(1);
                            /*
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const TermScreen()
                            )
                            );*/

                          }
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'continue'.toUpperCase(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),


                      ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          elevation: 0,
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 15.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed:  !emailRegex.hasMatch(_email) ? null : () {
                          if(_authKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            print(_email);
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, TermScreen.routeName,
                              arguments: ScreenArguments(
                                _email,
                              ),
                            );
                            //widget.onChangedStep(1);
                            /*
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const TermScreen()
                            )
                            );*/

                          }
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'continue'.toUpperCase(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),



                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

Tried to apply the official documentation, but i go some difficulties.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please try to be more precise, otherwise it will be difficult for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the docs try this, you should use `onGenerateRoute`. here i'm making you two classes `RouteConsts` which have  constants for your all screens and `RouteGenerator` which have the generate  function and return the routes accordingly.

```
class RouteConsts {
  static const String initialScreen = '/';
  static const String homeScreen = '/homeScreen';
  static const String termsScreen = '/TermsScreen';
  static const String passwordScreen = '/PasswordScreen';
}

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route generate(RouteSettings s) {
    Widget page;
    switch (s.name) {
      case RouteConsts.homeScreen:
        HomeScreenArguments args = s.arguments as HomeScreenArguments;
        page = HomeScreen(email: args.email);
        break;
      default:
        page = const Center(
          child: Text('Invalid route'),
        );
        break;
    }

    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page);
  }
}
```

and use it in main like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Chope Ton BTS',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: "/",
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generate,  // <- here is the RouteGenerator class 
    );
  }
}
```

In `RouteGenerator` you can see i have used `HomeScreenArguments` that's the model class having the exact same arguments as your screen, in my code i do like this i make this model above the stateless or stateful class. like this:

```
class HomeScreenArguments {
  final String email;

  HomeScreenArguments({required this.email});
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String email;

  const HomeScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.email,
  });

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late final String localEmail;

  @override
  void initState() {
    /// Here like this you can take a local variable and get the value.
    localEmail = widget.email;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      /// Or you can use directly use it like this.
      child: Text(widget.email),
    );
  }
}
```

and on navigating you can give values like this:

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteConsts.homeScreen,
              arguments: HomeScreenArguments(email: 'working@dart.flutter'));
        },
        child: const Text('Navigate'));
  }
}
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be an efficient system to manage the routes.
I have a difficulty to apply it. 
In your class "HomeScreenArguments", can you write how you get (show?) the content of args.email ? thanks

Comment: Sure, Here in `HomeScreenArguments args = s.arguments as HomeScreenArguments;` this like i'm taking args as HomeScreenArguments and assigning it with `s.argument` where `s` we are getting from function parameter `Route generate(RouteSettings s)` and it'll having the arguments which you pass from the `Navigator`. And as we are also passing this same model from navigator we will get the values in args, so then you use it in giving to the `HomeScreen` with `args.email`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what i understood. In HomeScreen, I do something like that : 
`class _TermsScreenState extends State<TermsScreen> {
  late final String email ="";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
        'MAIL :$email';
...
  }
}
`
I must initialize email and give him a value "", else i go an error. So how to get the value which we send to him ?
I do this :
`case RouteConsts.termsScreen:
        AuthScreenArguments args = s.arguments as AuthScreenArguments;
        page = TermsScreen(email: args.email);
        break;
`
Thanks.

Comment: No, see If you make a `StatefulWIdget`(here your TermsScreen is StatetfulWidget) it make two class one is TermsScreen and other is _TermsScreenState and the value you're passing with Navigator and Argument data model will be in the TermsScreen's variables not in the `_TermsScreenState`. and for using it in the _TermsScreenState you need to use it as `widget.email`. You must me getting confuse because i'm using `StatelessWidget` in the `HomeScreen` let me change my answer for `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: i have updated my answer try now and let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your precisions! It's work, and u learn me this system!